# Method not required for GET? If so, is it common not to write it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails, and I was thinking that a method should be defined for every single route.

However, `/hello_world` works as long as I write as below:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/hello_world", to: "hello#world"
end
```

```rb
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  # no world
end
```

```
# app/views/hello/world.html.erb
hello world!
```

Is it an expected behavior? If so, is it common not to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a controller action if you have any processing / data retrieval that you need to do before you display the view.

So, yes, the method itself isn't necessarily needed.

You might need to retrieve a record in a `show` action like this...

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

but inn some cases, you might have a `before_action` that does whatever's neeeded for several methods, so you (again) don't need to specify the action method.

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  private
  def set_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

So this is a case where you might have needed to define a method for the action, but you've now made it unneccessary.